# ElasticSearch query size limit?

Tags: elasticsearch, limit

Does ElasticSearch have a size limit on its JSON queries?

e.g. If I filter using ids, and I build up a list of 1 million+ ids, will the request be rejected?

In theory there must be a ceiling. But I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: Which API are you asking for ? If you are going to use search API with terms query there is a limit of 65,536 terms https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Comment: Actually this is perfect. Yes I'm using the search API with terms.

Answer (score 3):

> indices.query.bool.max_clause_count (Static, integer) Maximum number
> of clauses a Lucene BooleanQuery can contain. Defaults to 1024

Refer to this official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-settings.html), to know more about this setting

Add the following configuration in the `elasticsearch.yml` file to increase the maximum number of clauses.

```
indices.query.bool.max_clause_count:4096
```